# Opt-in registration of Razor Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0, asp.net-core-configuration

To use a Razor [Class Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-6.0) in a client project, one adds a `<ProjectReference>.` That  *references* the library's pages and static assets, and automatically *registers* them - I don't need to perform any other config.

Is it possible to have an "opt in" *registration* mechanism instead? The same as with other .NET libraries, where *referencing* them is not enough, one must also *register* them during startup, e.g.:

```cs
services.AddSomeLibrary();
```

Is there an equivalent way to *register* a Razor Class Library?

Comment: Not like you write it. Because project references are for the compiler, so compile time, while any dynamic code is runtime. Two different and separate worlds. You could have multiple csproj files having different project references and selectively compile one of them. But if you want to control dependencies during runtime, you require another mechanism.

Comment: @JHBonarius Agreed, razor pages are compiled so they are included at compile time. But the fact that they exist in the AppDomain doesn't mean the aspnet runtime should automatically run them - there must be a mechanism where they are sought (probably via assembly scanning) and then loaded and included in the routing table. So hopefully there is a way to hook into that process.

Comment: You want custom mapping? Maybe look around here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions

Comment: Also look at the configurable variant of AddRazorPages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvcservicecollectionextensions.addrazorpages?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-mvcservicecollectionextensions-addrazorpages(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-system-action((microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-razorpages-razorpagesoptions)))